# Overriding get_queryset leads to caching headache in ListView, where data remains stale

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

Could someone explain why overriding `get_queryset` and referencing the queryset via `self` completely caches the page? I need to wait 5 minutes or more before updates made to the database display.

I'm trying to save a temporary value to the each object and pass it to the template.

I've got everything working fine and dandy in example 3 but don't really understand what I did to make it work, so any insight would be great!

## Example 1: Caches for several minutes, but r.css='abc' work ok

```
class AppointmentListView(ListView):
    qs = Appointment.objects.prefetch_related('client', 'patients')

    def get_queryset(self):
        for r in self.qs:
            r.css = 'abc' #<-passes temp value to template ok
        return self.qs
```

## Example 2: No caching problem but r.css='abc' now does not work

If I don't include a method and just have the queryset called automatically, there is no caching and database updates display immediately, but my temp data does not reach template.
    class AppointmentListView(ListView):

```
    queryset = Appointment.objects.prefetch_related('client','patients')

    for r in queryset:
        r.css = 'abc' #<- NOT passed to template
```

## Example 3: No caching problem AND r.css='abc' works fine

Finally if I put everything in the method, it all works fine - temp data reaches the template and there's no caching.

```
class AppointmentListView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Appointment.objects.prefetch_related('client','patients')
        for r in qs:
            r.css = 'abc' #<-passes to template ok

        return qs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is how Python evaluates your code. Below is a simplified example that explains what you're seeing.

```
import random

class Example1(object):
    roll = random.randint(1, 6) # this is evaluated immediately!
    def get_roll(self):
        return self.roll

ex1 = Example1()

# the call below always returns the same number! 
# (until Python re-interprets the class)
ex1.get_roll()
```

If you type the code above into a python interpreter, you'll notice that `ex1.get_roll()` always returns the same number!

`Example1.roll` is known as a class or static variable. These are evaluated only once when the class is defined.

```
class Example2(object):
    def get_number(self):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        return roll
```

In `Example2`, a new random number is generated everytime `get_roll` method is called.

For the examples listed in your question:

**Example 1**

`qs` is a class variable, and thus only gets evaluated once (which is why you see the "caching" behavior). Subsequent calls to `get_queryset` returns the same `qs` variable that was initially evaluated.

**Example 2**

You didn't override `get_queryset`, which means `ListView.get_queryset` implementation is used.

Django's `ListView.get_queryset` copies the `queryset` before evaluating it - which is why you don't see "caching". However, because the queryset is copied, the effects from your for loop is thrown away.

**Example 3**

This is generally the correct way to write your code. You should write your methods like this if you don't want to see "caching" behavior.